# Identity Server 4 tokens signing

Tags: c#, identityserver4

Identity Server 4 supposed to use tokens signing by certificate on production environment. Is it secure to use self signing certificate to sign tokens?

Answer (score 0):

It's for your organization to decide.

```
The biggest challenge with self-signed certificates is that security teams often lack visibility over how many they have, where they are installed, who owns them, and how the private key is stored. It’s hard enough keeping track of certificates issued by a number of different public and private CAs. It’s virtually impossible to keep track of self-signed certificates issued without any formal request or approval process.

If the corporate network is breached, there is no way of knowing if a self-signed certificate (and it’s private key) has been compromised. Compromised self-signed certificates can pose many security challenges, since attackers can spoof the identity of the victim. Unlike CA-issued certificates, self-signed certificates cannot be revoked. The inability to quickly find and revoke private key associated with a self-signed certificate creates serious risk.
```

https://www.keyfactor.com/blog/self-signed-certificate-risks/

The risks with self-signed certificates is pretty well documented via your favorite search engine.
Whether that's an acceptable risk for your use-case and organization, is a decision you'll have to make on your end.